# Not root access

Tags: linux, root

I would like to install https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894212/installing-pyrouge-gets-error-in-ubuntu using Astariul's answer. I have no problem until step 4 where I need to install sudo apt-get install libxml-parser-perl. However, on the server, I don't have root access. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: No; There isn’t a workaround; Have someone with root access perform the appropriate commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the package is for a perl module, so yes, it should be possible. Instead of the debian package, you can install the perl module itself and make sure it's in the import path when the other app runs it.

You can find the details about installing local modules from cpan here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980297/how-can-i-use-cpan-as-a-non-root-user

This likely won't be trivial, so make sure you understand the steps and what you're trying to achieve. If the system is also missing libxml itself, you may need to compile it in your home directory and ensure cpan/perl can find it when installing the modules.